# LibreOffice Basic: existing utilities for splitting strings?

Tags: string, split, libreoffice, basic

I'm using the LibreOffice Basic language.

I'm wondering if there is any library anywhere I can use for splitting strings into arrays? For example, suppose I have the following string with items separated by an arbitrary number of spaces:

```
ABC   DEF GHI
```

I'd like to split this string into an array called "item" with the following elements:

```
item(0) = "ABC"
item(1) = "DEF"
item(2) = "GHI"
```

I know how to produce these results in LibreOffice Basic using regular expressions or via iterating character-by-character through the original string, but I'm wondering if there are any existing functions or helper utilities I can use, so I don't have to "re-invent the wheel".

Internet searches have not yielded anything, but I could possibly have overlooked something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Item = Split(StringName," ")`?  I suspect each space would make its own entry in the array, but perhaps dealing with blank array entries would be easier than iterating through the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will need to write your own function.  There are several ideas at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=33218.

If you will be doing a lot of string manipulation and the project is not too far along yet, then it might be worth considering another UNO-enabled language like Java or Python.  In Python the code would be simply:

```py
s = "ABC   DEF GHI"
item = s.split()
```

Comment: Thank you. I had missed that discussion in the OpenOffice forum. But yes, I think Python would be the best way to go. I've just been getting started trying to integrate Python into Calc for a different purpose, and it should also be good for this and other string-manipulation functions.